# Selenium Steam community market listings python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, steam

I am trying to write a program which would open a steam community page and would then read the first value in the table of prices. I will then do stuff with this afterwards. I do not want to use the steam api if that is anyones suggestion i would like to know how to select the first id in the table because it will constantly change and I cannot define a set id and trying to locate by class is proving difficult.

My code can currently open the webpage that is not an issue

Example of item from community market.

```
<div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">

<span class="market_table_value">
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee"></span>
    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you are working with [this page](http://steamcommunity.com/market/).

To get the list of prices, iterate over results containing in the `div` elements with `market_listing_row` class and get the text of the elements with `market_listing_their_price` class:

```
for result in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.market_listing_row"):
    price = result.find_element_by_css_selector("div.market_listing_their_price")
    print price.text.strip()
```

This would print price results like these:

```
Starting at: $0.63
Starting at: $0.27
```

Comment: would that work for this page aswell http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Pistol

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo yup, the locators look the same, try it out.

Comment: how did you identify these as the css selectors?

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo I've just used browser developer tools and inspected the desired elements

Comment: im doing that but it won't work for the next thing. I'm trying to make a list of every marketable item in tf2 and so im using this link and i am trying to record every named item, ill post it as a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233974/continuation-of-selenium-inquiry-regards-to-identifying-elements

Comment: Any idea what im missing?

Comment: @DanielPrinsloo sorry, was afk. Looks like you've solved your problem. Glad to see that.