# Writing from one file to another python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to take some information I got from a webpage and write one of the variables to a file however I am having no luck it is probably very easy but I'm lost. Here is an example of one of the rows there are 1253 rows.

```
<div class='entry qual-5 used-demoman slot-head bestprice custom' data-price='3280000' data-name="Kill-a-Watt Allbrero" data-quality="5" data-australium="normal" data-class="demoman" data-particle_effect="56" data-paint="" data-slot="cosmetic" data-consignment="consignment">
```

I am after the field called data-name it is not at the same spot in each row. I tried this but it did not work

```
mfile=open('itemlist.txt','r')
mfile2=open('output.txt','a')
for row in mfile:
    if char =='data-name':
        mfile2.write(char)
```

Edit 1:

I made an example file of 'hello hi peanut'
if did:

```
for row in mfile:
    print row.index('hello')
```

it would print 0 as expected however when I changed the hello to hi it didnt return 1 it returned nothing.

Comment: `char` is not defined in your code. You could use `row.index('data-name')` to figure out where the attribute begins. Then you can `index` again starting from that index to find the two quotation marks and use string manipulation to extract the value.

Comment: Could you put this as an answer with an example so I can accept it as an answer

Comment: I would actually want you to try it on your own first before showing you how to do it. So why don’t you give it a try and then if that fails, show what you have tried, and then we can try to explain you where you went wrong. That way, you learn best.

Comment: im trying it but i've found that it only looks at the first value and doesn't look at the rest of the values in the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s try to find the value using common string manipulation methods:

```
>>> line = '''<div class='entry qual-5 used-demoman slot-head bestprice custom' data-price='3280000' data-name="Kill-a-Watt Allbrero" data-quality="5" data-australium="normal" data-class="demoman" data-particle_effect="56" data-paint="" data-slot="cosmetic" data-consignment="consignment">'''
```

We can use [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) to find the position of a string within a string:

```
>>> line.index('data-name')
87
```

So now we know we need to start looking at index `87` for the attribute we are interested in:

```
>>> line[87:]
'data-name="Kill-a-Watt Allbrero" data-quality="5" data-australium="normal" data-class="demoman" data-particle_effect="56" data-paint="" data-slot="cosmetic" data-consignment="consignment">'
```

Now, we need to remove the `data-name="` part too:

```
>>> start = line.index('data-name') + len('data-name="')
>>> start
98
>>> line[start:]
'Kill-a-Watt Allbrero" data-quality="5" data-australium="normal" data-class="demoman" data-particle_effect="56" data-paint="" data-slot="cosmetic" data-consignment="consignment">'
```

Now, we just need to find the index of the closing quotation mark too, and then we can extract just the attribute value:

```
>>> end = line.index('"', start)
>>> end
118
>>> line[start:end]
'Kill-a-Watt Allbrero'
```

And then we have our solution:

```
start = line.index('data-name') + len('data-name="')
end = line.index('"', start)
print(line[start:end])
```

We can put that in the loop:

```
with open('itemlist.txt','r') as mfile, open('output.txt','a') as mfile2w
    for line in mfile:
        start = line.index('data-name') + len('data-name="')
        end = line.index('"', start)
        mfile2.write(line[start:end])
        mfile2.write('\n')
```

Comment: Pretty instructive and helpful answer. +1

Comment: I am trying this but i noticed that you left my broken loop in so im trying to fix that now but when i say print start and print end to check that it is finding the line.index values nothing comes out?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I copy/pasted too much without looking, fixed that code at the end now :)

Comment: I tried this and it isn't working for me nothing is writing or printing even when i add print start after the definition of start

Comment: Hmm, that’s weird. Try printing the line right after `for line in mfile` to see if any lines actually appear.

Comment: Yeah your right nothing prints out i tried printing hello straight afterwards and nothing comes out

Comment: I AM SUCH AN IDIOT im so sorry i was usin the wrong python version

Comment: Haha, don’t worry, but I’m glad you could figure it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

**a.html**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Asdf </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class='entry qual-5 used-demoman slot-head bestprice custom' data-price='3280000' data-name="Kill-a-Watt Allbrero" data-quality="5" data-australium="normal" data-class="demoman" data-particle_effect="56" data-paint="" data-slot="cosmetic" data-consignment="consignment">

    </body>
</html>
```

**a.py**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('a.html') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(lines), 'html.parser')
result = soup.findAll('div')[0]['data-price']
print result
# prints 3280000
```

My opinion is, if your task is pretty easy as in your example, there is actually no need of using `beautifulsoup`. However, if it is more complicated, or it will be more complicated. Consider giving it a try with `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: The `BeautifulSoup` module name suggests that you are using version 3, which is pretty old and does not support Python 3. Please update to BeautifulSoup 4 and change the module name in your answer to `bs4`.

Comment: I proudly prefer using `Python 2.7.6` unless the OP explicitly asks for a `Python 3` solution. There is only `Python` tag in the question as far as I see.

Comment: Sure, but bs4 works in Python 2.6+ too, and it generally seems like a bad idea to promote outdated, and no-longer updated libraries when a newer version exists (especially when all you have to do is change it to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`)

Comment: @poke Okay, that makes sense.. I updated my answer to `bs4` with keeping `print result` to show it is still `Python 2` :-)

Comment: Yes, that’s totally fine with me; my issue was only with the old module name. Thanks :)